# Normal highlight group changes cursor color in vim in xterm

Tags: terminal, highlight, cursor

I set the following highlight:

```
:hi Normal ctermfg=250 ctermbg=235
```

The text is a nice light gray on dark gray, as intended. But the cursor has become dark blue. I'd love to have it just be the reverse of Normal.

[image: desc]

Setting similar Normal highlights has different effects:

- `:hi Normal ctermfg=250 ctermbg=234` medium blue
- `:hi Normal ctermfg=250 ctermbg=233` green
- `:hi Normal ctermfg=250 ctermbg=232` teal

Of course, those also change the background as expected. Changing the `ctermfg` doesn't seem to do anything to the cursor color.

I'm using Vim 8.0 (also tried 7.4) on CentOS 7 via xterm (`term=xterm-256color`).
(Update: I'm ssh-ing to the CentOS system from SecureCRT 8 on Windows 10. My SecureCRT session is set to xterm emulation.)

[Escape codes for xterm](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor#Changing_the_cursor_color_in_insert_mode) have no effect on the cursor color.
There doesn't seem to be anything in [`:help hi-normal-cterm`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahi-normal-cterm) about cursor color.
[Someone who knows a lot more about xterm than me says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289676/128023) that it should just invert the fg/bg colors.

I don't know much about terminal types and such, but is there a way I can get my cursor to a normal color combo?

Comment: In the xterm bash prompt, can you show the result of `ps x | grep $PPID` ?

Comment: @tivn `30043 ?        S      0:00 sshd: <username>@pts/22` (besides the grep line)

Comment: @P1 Can you first exit your ssh session before running the command? Actually I am expecting `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` etc. Cursor color usually controlled by your terminal setting rather then by the vim itself -- unless you use gvim. Are you using CentOS 7 ?

Comment: @tivn Aha! I ssh'ed to the CentOS 7 system from SecureCRT (with xterm emulation) in Win 10.
When I ssh'ed from a MacOS terminal and vim'ed, I got the gray cursor I expected.
So the problem isn't where I thought. Is SecureCRT's xterm emulation broken? Where should I be looking?

Comment: I don't think it is broken. I am not using SecureCRT but I found there is setting to change its cursor color: https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/colorconfig.html

Comment: Where do you see the cursor setting?
(I have already set the session to xterm as suggested in the penultimate Q&A there.)

Comment: Check first screenshot in the URL. Terminal => Appearance => Cursor .